# Why cant I add dynos to my heroku project?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have tried everything and cannot figure out why it wont create dynos. I have a java web app using maven, deploys to heroku successfully but does not have dynos.
Procfile declares types -> (none) but why?
My error:

```
 at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path= method=GET path="/list"  host=employee-db10.herokuapp.com request_id=some_request_id fwd="XX.XXX.XX.XXXX" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My procfile is as follows:

```
web:  java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

I have also tried this for my procfile and it did not work:

```
web: java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war --port $PORT
```

I also see this in my build log and it could also be a problem. I tried building this using a war earlier and switched over to webapp-runner after reading online.

```
remote:        [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for jsp-servlet-jdbc-mysql-example:jsp-servlet-jdbc-mysql-example:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: "My procfile is as follows"—is it called `procfile` or `Procfile`? That's significant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `heroku ps:scale` command to add (or remove) dynos at will:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

This command will instruct Heroku to run a single `web` process (as specified in your `Procfile`). If you'd like to have 2 dynos, you could say:

```
heroku ps:scale web=2
```

Etc. [Here's an article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling) from Heroku's docs that explain it in more detail.

Comment: when I run "heroku ps:scale web=1" i get this reponse - "scaling dynos ....! Couldnt find that process type  (web)."

Comment: Ah! In that case, it certainly sounds like @Chris from the comment on your main post was right. The procfile must be named `Procfile` (with a capital P) for Heroku to recognize it. Can you confirm that your procfile is named that way?

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks so much for the help to both of you